# Shellcode searching for Bytes String: 0C330408Bh

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, malware, shellcode, malware-detection

I am learning how malware(Blackhole Exploit) works. I extracted the shellcode from a malicious code. I figured out everything except a search for the Byte String. Can anyone help me with this? Why does this shellcode (most of the malicious shellcodes) search for this particular string?
The searching code goes like this:

```
mov   eax, 0C330408BH;
inc   esi
cmp   dword ptr [esi], eax
jne   //back to top//
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take the magic bytes, convert them to little-endian format and disassemble, you get the following:

```
8B 40 30    mov     eax, [eax+30h]
C3          retn
```

So, the shellcode is searching for this sequence of instructions. I'm not 100% sure but I think it's used to find kernel32 image in memory (since this sequence usually occurs there).

Comment: yeah it is used to find the kernel32 image in memory. Thanks for the clarification. But still i wonder, why dont the author hardcode it rather than giving the byte string search?

Answer (score 3):

As an addition to the Igor's answer, I recommend you to read this article http://skypher.com/index.php/2010/11/17/bypassing-eaf/. The code looks for the specific instructions within system DLLs to use them for reading or writing data from/to arbitrary locations in memory. So to use this code just put the (address-0x30) to eax, and call the sequence above.